# Trying to integrate exponent distribution (problems with arithmetic of integration)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to integrate exponent distribution which is defined as:
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x\ge 0 \\ 0 & x\le 0 \end{cases} $$
Now i remember that integrating improper integral would go something like this ?
$$F(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(s)ds=\lim_{n\rightarrow (-\infty)} \int_{n}^{x}f(s)ds=\lim_{n\rightarrow (-\infty)}\left[\begin{matrix} \end{matrix} F(x)-F(n) \right]
$$ 
I end up with result as following:
$$ F(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}ds=\lim_{n\rightarrow(-\infty)}(-e^{-\lambda x})-(-e^{-\lambda n}) $$ Now the end result should be following:

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(s) \, ds=\begin{cases} 1-e^{-\lambda x}, & x> 0. \\
0, & x\le 0\end{cases}$$

This hints that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow (-\infty)}-(-e^{\lambda n})=1 $$ but i cant understand why.

Now if someon could provide some answer to this that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this case $f(x)$ vanishes for $x<0$, so that

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}{\rm d}x~f(x)
$$

can be evaluated in two steps

> $x<0$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^x{\rm d}x~ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x{\rm d}x~ 0 = 0
$$

> $x\ge0$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^x{\rm d}x~ f(x) = \int_{0}^x{\rm d}x~ \lambda e^{-\lambda x} = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}
$$

Comment: $$ e^{-\lambda*0}=e^{0}=1 $$ i think this makes sense now.

Comment: also is the $dx$ intentionally before $f(x)$ or is this accidental ?

Comment: @Tuki It is a matter of notation 

$$
\int {\rm d}s~g(s) = \int g(s){\rm d}s
$$

Comment: Sorry i didn't know this was possible notation.